# How to switch to another TAB through selenium webdriver and python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tabs, webdriver

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import autoit
wait = WebDriverWait
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.arttoframe.com/search")
action = ActionChains(driver)
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="apply_frame_main_0"]')
action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(link).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
time.sleep(2)
```

C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\untitled3\ATF_TestOrder.py

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

To open a *Pictute Frame* in the adjacent *TAB* and switch to it you can use **ActionChains** as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.arttoframe.com/search")
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='apply_frame_main_0']")))
  windows_before  = driver.current_window_handle
  ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(element).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
  windows_after = driver.window_handles
  new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0]
  driver.switch_to_window(new_window)
  print(driver.title)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  8x10 Satin Black picture frame
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: switch_to_new_tab]